# Deta.space does not return login token even login successful by command "deta login"

Tags: python, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEb2E.png)

As you can see, my project is already there and I can't do anything as I can't go on. I am completely new and using Mac Mini M1 with macOS Version 13.4 (22F66). I try countless time with different browsers but get the same result.

I want to create my python app on deta space.

Comment: Try using `space login`, the platform seems to be updated...